# LED switch behaviour

Tags: resistance, circuit-design, button

I'm going to use one of those [LED-buttons](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/powey-symbol-head-16mm-light-switch-latching-anti-vandal-on-off-push-button-switvch-waterproof-switch/32391047048.html) to switch a certain (5V) appliance. It's possible to use a couple of connection types:
[image]

Le left side scheme is OK, but I don't like it.
I would go with the right side one, but the problem is in that situation the voltage drops... 5V drops to ~3V and 12V to ~10V... 
I think should be due to an "embedded" resistor protecting the LED.

In your opinion, is there something I can do to circumvent this problem?
(I need all the 5V).

Thanks.

Comment: Your switch has both Normally-Open and a Normally-Closed terminals. I suggest you investigate using the one you're not presently using.

Comment: Why don't you like the left side schematic?

Comment: I think I see why - the LED is always on.  (I mistook the 'power' and 'equipment' connections.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right side circuit is not usually a good way to wire an LED for the very reason you mentioned (unless that voltage drop is intended).  Also the diagram label is incorrect where it states "light on when open switch".  The LED will come on only when the switch is closed.

Based on the voltage drop you saw testing the right side circuit, it doesn't seem there is any series resistor, so you must include one to prevent burning out the LED.

I think this is what you are looking for, where the LED only comes on when the switch is on, but the load still gets full voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBPLiU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Angelo, I'll try this diagram. Another thing: the LED it's rated for 12V and I already tried to light it alone on the 5V. It doesn't get really bright, but that's enough. Do you think I can leave out the resistor?

Comment: It works perfectly! (with no resistor) Thanks again.    :

Comment: Glad you are happy with the results.  Yes, if they state the LED is good for 12V it should be fine.  Their drawing suggests there is an internal resistor (because they don't include an external one), but I saw other things that made be not trust the drawing too much.